# Git fetch remote branch into new local branch (with one command)

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have my local repo with *master tracking remote A's *master. (Remote A's *master is its only active branch.)

Remote B now has a *prbranch that has some extra work not in A/master. My local repo doesn't have any reference to any remote besides A (and my personal remote that is only used for pushing).

How can I a) fetch B/prbranch into my local repo and b) create a new local branch with the same name and changes automatically?

`git fetch B prbranch` correctly fetches the branch, but puts it into FETCH_HEAD with which I have to manually create a like-named branch.

`git pull B prbranch` is of course useless, trying to merge into the current local branch

and `git clone --single-branch B prbranch` just makes a new repo in a subfolder of the current repo.

So how can I fetch the remote branch AND create an identical local branch in one command? Surely this isn't hard to do...

(My experience is of course limited, so I expect that the answer will be simple and "retroactively obvious".)

Comment: use `git remote add` to add remote B as a new remote

Comment: Why would I do that? I only want to one time fetch this arbitrary branch, never using the remote again

Comment: oh - just change your fetch to prBranch:prBranch or manually create a branch pointing to FETCH_HEAD afterwards then.

Comment: Ah, I see, ditto the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following command will fetch and create a local branch without creating a remote tracking branch:

```
git fetch <urlB> refs/heads/prbranch:refs/heads/prbranch
```

See [Git Internals - The Refspec](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec) on the documentation.

Comment: Just prbranch:prbranch worked, as Andrew C pointed out above. I didn't understand te power of refspecs, and that the last argument was more than just a branch name :)

Comment: I still kinda wish I could do `git fetch B branch:` and have git use the remote name for the local branch name as well... but now I'm just getting picky :)

Comment: Right, as Andrew points out the least you need is prbranch:prbranch for remote branch to working branch.  The refspec will work for any ref under `.git/refs`, so sometimes it's a good idea to spell it out to avoid confusion.